# Choice of time representation in redis database

Tags: c++, redis

I need to store date and time stamps in a redis database from C++. I have a choice of using std::chrono, ctime or textual representation for the time stamp. Which one should I prefer, and why, for portability. With portability I mean here the ability to to read the time stamp from different programming languages/operating systems.

Comment: Be a bit more detailed; what OS are you on, what's the target server? I don't think there will be any big issue with portability because of neither OS nor language. From my experience the portability is usually a regional issue.

Comment: Well, the idea is that I cannot be specific as the timestamp could be read on different OS:s and using different languagues, that I do not know now. But the application where I am writing the value is C++ on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most portable time storage would be Unix timestamp stored as an integer.
It is language,OS and timezone agnostic.
And this will give you memory footprint benefits as well, as an integer is highly memory optimized datatype.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I opted for also.